# unable to send a request to MySQL database from xcode using arabic characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have a DB that contains a list of names and comment for each name, i'm listing that names in a tableview with no problems, but when i click on an a name to get the comment for it i get no results, only arabic names, but when i select a english name i get the result. so i think the problem is from xcode that can`t send the link if it have arabic characters.

when i put the link in safari, i get the result for english and arabic names, so i`m sure my php code is fine.

the code i'm using in xcode is

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *tempTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/getComment.php?name=%@",tempTitle];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"url : %@", strURL);
NSLog(@"result : %@", strResult);
NSLog(@"title : %@", tempTitle);
}
```

any idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by replacing with this code

```
NSData *dataURL =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```